# Explaining jQuery AJAX Success Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to use this jQuery script and this is confusing me:

```
function CallService() 
        {
                $.ajax({
                    type        : varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                    url         : varUrl, // Location of the service
                    data        : varData, //Data sent to server
                    contentType : varContentType, // content type sent to server
                    dataType    : varDataType, //Expected data format from server
                    processdata : varProcessData, //True or False
                    success     : function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
                    ServiceSucceeded(msg);                    
                    },
                    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
                });
        }
```

The bit im confused about is the sucess object. The jQuery documentation says:

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)Function, Array

A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.
```

But this method signature looks nothing like the:

```
success     : function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
                        ServiceSucceeded(msg);                    
                        }
```

Object that we seem to be passing in.

Questions:

1) What does `function(msg){ServiceSucceeded(msg)}` mean?

2) What is 'msg' in this context?

3) How on earth am I meant to know how to structure the method sugnature for sucess?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perfectly reasonable question. :-) In JavaScript, you don't necessarily have to call a function with as many args as it defines, and you don't have to define as many args as you may get called with. Which can be confusing if you're used to more constrained environments. :-)

Answering specifics:

> 1) What does function(msg){ServiceSucceeded(msg)} mean?

It defines a function (an anonymous one) that accepts one named argument (`msg`) and calls `ServiceSucceded` passing in that arg. jQuery will call the function with the three arguments defined by the jQuery documentation for the `success` function, but this particular `success` function is only using the first of those (`data`). More about named functions vs. anonymous functions [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html).

> 2) What is 'msg' in this context?

The first argument to the function. jQuery's docs call this first argument `data`, but you can call it whatever you like.

> 3) How on earth am I meant to know how to structure the method sugnature for sucess?

You did the right thing, it's in the jQuery documentation.

This thing about function arguments can be confusing, so let's do some examples:

```
function foo(arg) {
    alert(arg);
}
```

That's perfectly clear, I'm defining a function called `foo` that takes a single named argument, `arg`. And thus:

```
foo("Hi there"); // alerts "Hi there"
```

But I can also do this:

```
foo(); // alerts "undefined"
```

There, I didn't give any arguments for `foo`, and so within `foo`, `arg` is undefined.

I can also do this:

```
foo("Hi there", "again"); // alerts "Hi there"
```

I'm calling `foo` with **two** arguments, but `foo` only makes use of one of them.

I could define `foo` to use as many arguments as you pass in:

```
function foo() {
    var index;

    for (index = 0; index < arguments.length; ++index) {
        alert(arguments[index]);
    }
}
```

`arguments` is an automatic thing all functions have, which is a pseudo-array (it's not really an `Array`) of the actual arguments the function was called with. And so:

```
foo("Hi there", "again"); // alerts "Hi there", and then alerts "again"
```

You can even mix named and unnamed arguments:

```
function foo(arg) {
    var index;

    alert(arg);
    for (index = 1; index < arguments.length; ++index) {
        alert("[" + arguments[index] + "]");
    }
}
```

So now

```
foo("Hi there", "again"); // alerts "Hi there" and then alerts "[again]"
```

Note the `[]` around the second alert, because I started looping with index `1` rather than zero.

`arguments` and named args are connected:

```
function foo(arg) {
    alert("arg = " + arg);
    alert("arguments[0] = " + arguments[0]);
    arg = "Updated";
    alert("arg = " + arg);
    alert("arguments[0] = " + arguments[0]);
}
```

If I do `foo("Hi");`, that shows these alerts:

```
arg = Hi
arguments[0] = Hi
arg = Updated
arguments[0] = Updated
```

(It goes the other way, too, if you update `arguments[0]`.)

Comment: Hi TJ, your answer really helped thanks alot I can see whats going on now will simplyfy a bit.

Comment: Just read your update this is really helpful it explains alot now. I never realised that javascript could be 'overloaded'? in such a way...

Comment: @Pete2k: No worries, glad that helped! Yeah, JavaScript functions are very free-form, which makes them quite powerful, with all the pros and cons that implies. ;-)

Comment: I love reading great answers like this on SO.  Thanks!  You helped me understand this whole process better as well.

Answer (score 7):

The function is passed 3 parameters: `data`, `status`, and the `jqXHR` object.  `data` is what is returned from the AJAX call, `status` is the HTTP status code (I think), and `jqXHR` is a jQuery wrapped XHR object.

In this script, they only care about the data parameter, and not the other two.

So using `success: function(msg)`, they only get the `data` parameter.  The other two are sent, but ignored.

`ServiceSucceeded` is just a function that is being called with the `data` parameter sent to it.

`success: ServiceSucceeded` could have also worked here.

Comment: `textStatus` (`status`, as you referenced it above) is not the status code. It is === to `"success"` if successful, and presumably `"error"` otherwise. Don't ask me what the point is, if you can just specify success/error functions.

Answer (score 2):

1. It means the success handler invokes `ServiceSucceeded` with the response of the request.
2. `msg` contains the response from the request. `msg` maps to `data` in the jQuery documentation.
3. You need to look into the jQuery documentation for finding the signature.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the success function is defined as taking three parameters (as per the documentation you quoted), those three parameters are not mandatory - Javascript is very forgiving about this sort of thing; if you miss a parameter from a function call, it simply gets set to `underfined`, so as long as you don't try to use it, JS won't throw any errors.

The code you've provided only gives one parameter - `msg` - but in JS, this is perfectly valid; it just means that `msg` will be the `data` parameter defined in the docs, and `textStatus` and `jqXHR` will be undefined.

This is fine, as long as in your success function you don't actually want to use either of those parameters. If you want to use them, then pass them, but if not, it's fine to drop them. You're writing the success function, so you get to decide which of the three parameters to use.

Answer (score 2):

jquery Ajax is a way for you to communicate with the server (PHP, ASP, whatever).  Let's assume you use PHP. the function "callService()" send a request to "varUrl" (validation.php, i.e) and get (or POST -> varType) the content (varContentType -> valdation.php?id=1231&whatever=soemthing).  The purpose of this is to get some server side data without reloading the page.  If you want the validation.php to **echo** some **html**, then the dataType in the Ajax function must be "html".  See jquery.com for more info on dataType.

The success parameter is a function handler for the server response.  Success is called if you get a response from the server corresponding to the dataType you asked (html, json, text, whatever). In that perticular case, if the server respond correctly, the function "ServiceSucceeded" is called with the attribute "msg" which is the server response you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

1) That function is called if the AJAX request is successful i.e. a success status code is returned by the server being contacted.

2) I would assume that 'msg' is the data returned from the server. The other two arguments are not supplied and therefore not used.

3) Use the Jquery documentation, and fiddle around until you get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is an *anonymous function*.
   It's like a regular function, but without a name.
2. `msg` is the function's first parameter.
3. By reading the documentation.